# What are the best wiki engine with good authorization features?

Tags: authorization, wiki

What is the best wiki engine with good authorization features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DokuWiki**](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) is a great open source PHP Wiki, clean syntax, straightforward install, simple report for read-only and private pages, plus a full ACL system, and a active community of plugin developers.

**[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)** is amazing from a feature stand point, if you need SVG and MathML support, but I find it too hard to customize and hack on personally.

Answer (score 2):

They use [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) in some subjects at my uni.  It has really good authorisation, controlled via simple ACLs at the top of each page.  Each student submits work on pages private to them and the subject staff, so it definitely seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

We use [atlassian confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) it has authorization features like restricting viewing or editing of pages for groups or users. But it's a commercial product (not free)

Answer (score 0):

Define "good". =)

Some would say that the original wiki script has the best authorization features in a [wiki](http://wiki.org/wiki.cgi?WhatIsWiki) sense of the word, seeing that Ward Cunningham defined Wiki as:

> The simplest online database that
>   could possibly work.

That said, I can share my experience with hosting [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) sites and that is that I often find that I would like to be able to define privileges on a group/page and group/section kind of way. But it always depends on the application. I use [UseModWiki](http://www.usemod.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl) for [robowiki.net](http://robowiki.net) and it works excellently even though it has the most rudimentary authorization system (next after the original wiki script then).